# How do I remove spots from my new ceramic tiles?

Tags: kitchens, cleaning, tile, ceramic-tile

I just laid dark brown ceramic tile in my kitchen. After grouting and cleaning I still have spots and round circles (from the cleaning bucket's bottom) on the floor. I have tried soap and water and scrubbing each tile with a soft scouring sponge, but the spots and circles are still there.

How do I remove these marks?

Answer (score 2):

It is likely grout haze.  Wait a week, daily damp mop the grout lines.  Then carefully use a haze remover sparingly (it is an acidic product) The marks will come right up.  Well rinse all areas of any solution, especially any that gets on the grout.

I made the mistake of not sealing a matte bisque mosaic hex floor tile before grouting early in my tile career.  I then used the haze cleaner too early.  It cleaned the haze alright.  It also removed some color from the grout.  I had to go back and hand stain the grout lines individually.  That's why I'm suggesting a week of curing for your grout.

Comment: After it dries the next day, seal your grout lines for MUCH easier cleanup in the future.  I like Miracle products, but many others are available and the review http://www.tilecleaning.org/grout-sealer-review.htm liked Aquamix.  YMMV

Answer (score 0):

I had glazed porcelain tiles put in "cheaply"and there were a couple bucket marks left that drove me crazy. I had no idea what they were from and didn't trust that the tile layer hadn't ruined them. I tried DUPONT haze remover, CRUD CUTTER, vinegar and baking soda (which worked partly), but then while cleaning something else with a Magic Eraser I tried it on the circles and finally they came off!!